# Why does water taste different after a workout?

Tags: water

I noticed this years ago and it's always intrigued me. When I drink water after an exhausting workout the water tastes different.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention if there is a specific taste you notice; I taste metal during and after an intense workout which apparently is caused by the heart not being able to keep up http://www.livestrong.com/article/322820-metallic-taste-in-the-mouth-during-exercise/.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an exercise specialist, so this is somewhat speculation, but I suspect that it's a combination of a) after exercise, you really feel like you need the water, so you're much more aware of it and your body tries to prompt you to drink more by making it a more pleasurable sensation and b) after working out, your body is flush with blood, including inside your mouth, where the constant flow of air has stimulated the tissues there, which means you're simply more sensitive.